# FFMPEG : syntax error: 'T�4��4' unexpected using FfmpegController for createSlideshowFromImagesAndAudio

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I have used https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java for create video with multiple images and audio file. 
But I could not generate expected output and got an error.
I have used https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java/blob/master/src/org/ffmpeg/android/FfmpegController.java for controller.

Below is my code:

```
File fileTmp = getCacheDir();
    try {
        mFfmpegController = new FfmpegController(this, fileTmp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String path = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder";
    final ArrayList<Clip> paths = new ArrayList<Clip>();

    File baseDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyFolder");
    File[] iFrameJpegs = baseDir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            Log.e("FileName", dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name);
            if (name.endsWith(".jpg"))
                paths.add(new Clip(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name));
            return name.endsWith(".jpg");
        }
    });

    Clip audio = new Clip(path + "/audio.mp3");
    Clip out = new Clip(path + "/ffmpeg.mp4");
    out.width = 480;
    out.height = 320;
    out.videoCodec = "libx264";
    out.audioCodec = "copy";

    try {
        mFfmpegController.createSlideshowFromImagesAndAudio(paths, audio, out, 2, new ShellUtils.ShellCallback() {
            @Override
            public void shellOut(String shellLine) {
                System.out.println("MIX> " + shellLine);
            }

            @Override
            public void processComplete(int exitValue) {

                if (exitValue != 0) {
                    System.err.println("concat non-zero exit: " + exitValue);
                    Log.d("ffmpeg","Compilation error. FFmpeg failed");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result: ffmpeg failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    if(new File( "/ffmpeg.mp4").exists()) {
                        Log.d("ffmpeg","Success file:"+ "/ffmpeg.mp4");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Below is code of error which i have got:

```
 I/FFmpeg controller: /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/cache/image-%03d.jpg
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/effect_hue.jpg -s 480x320/data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/cache/image-000.jpg 
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: 'T�4��4' unexpected
W/System.err: concat non-zero exit: 1
D/ffmpeg: Compilation error. FFmpeg failed
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/effect_hue.jpg -s 480x320/data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/cache/image-001.jpg 
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: 'T�4��4' unexpected
W/System.err: concat non-zero exit: 1
D/ffmpeg: Compilation error. FFmpeg failed
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/effect_engrave.jpg -s 480x320/data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/cache/image-002.jpg 
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: 'T�4��4' unexpected
W/System.err: concat non-zero exit: 1
D/ffmpeg: Compilation error. FFmpeg failed
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/effect_flea.jpg -s 480x320/data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/cache/image-003.jpg 
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: 'T�4��4' unexpected
W/System.err: concat non-zero exit: 1
D/ffmpeg: Compilation error. FFmpeg failed
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 357K, 5% free 8941K/9328K, paused 2ms, total 6ms
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/effect_grayscale.jpg -s 480x320/data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/cache/image-004.jpg 
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: 'T�4��4' unexpected
W/System.err: concat non-zero exit: 1
D/ffmpeg: Compilation error. FFmpeg failed
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -i 
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: 'T�4��4' unexpected
W/System.err: concat non-zero exit: 1
D/ffmpeg: Compilation error. FFmpeg failed
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -loop 0 -f image2 -r 1/2 -i /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/cache/image-%03d.jpg -strict -2/data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/cache/tmp.mpg 
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: 'T�4��4' unexpected
W/System.err: concat non-zero exit: 1
D/ffmpeg: Compilation error. FFmpeg failed
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -i/data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/cache/tmp.mpg -i /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/audio.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -acodec aac -b:a 128k -strict -2 -vcodec libx264/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/ffmpeg.mp4 
I/System.out: MIX> /data/data/com.orafox.vidmaker/app_bin/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: 'T�4��4' unexpected
W/System.err: concat non-zero exit: 1
D/ffmpeg: Compilation error. FFmpeg failed
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
```